# Angular $resource not binding?

Tags: angularjs

I have an issue where my first controller/view gets results from my $resource factory and works fine but my second controller/view does not seem to bind the parameters in the same way.

Service:

```
angular.module('taskerApp.services', ['ngResource']).
factory('taskQueries', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('http://www.timswiss.net/tasker/taskerdb.php?id=:task_id', 
        {}, //parameters
        {
            getTasks:   {method:'GET', params:{}, isArray:true}
        });
 }]);
```

Controllers:

```
angular.module('taskerApp.controllers', ['ui.bootstrap']).

controller('taskList', ['$scope', 'taskQueries', function($scope, taskQueries) {    
    $scope.tasks = taskQueries.getTasks();
}])

.controller('taskEdit', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'taskQueries', function($scope, $routeParams, taskQueries) {
    $scope.task = taskQueries.getTasks({task_id: $routeParams.task_id});
}]);
```

with the 'taskList' view:

```
{{tasks.length}} // returns the correct value (2)
<p ng-repeat="task in tasks">{{task.name}}</p> //works
{{tasks}} // works
```

but with the 'taskEdit' view:

```
{{task.length}} // returns the correct value (1)
<p ng-repeat="tas in task">{{tas.name}}</p> //produces nothing
{{task}} // looks the same as in previous view but with only 1 item - working?
```

So why does the first controller bind .name properly but not the second?

How can I get it to bind properly?

Comment: Did you set the controllers in the HTML?

Comment: Yes, through an `ng-view` and `config()`.  If I had not would the `{{task.length}}` in my second view still work?

Comment: The task.length can work due to the outer controller. Can you add your binding to **both** controllers to the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I fixed this by replacing

```
$scope.task = taskQueries.getTasks({task_id: $routeParams.task_id});
```

with

```
taskQueries.query({task_id: $routeParams.task_id}).$promise.then(function(data){
    $scope.task = data[0];
});
```